# Error Occured in Processing in SaEX

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, saex

We use Saex extension in ArcGIS for parcel updating. In some computers we get the error **Error Occurred in Processing**. I have attached the screenshot for reference.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saex always installs in D drive. When computer was updated the drive got changed to F. Changing it back to D made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

Some files for Saex may be missing or there may have been a version mismatch. Reinstallation should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some times error occurs when our database might not be updated with parcel key. once we have all the values fulfilled in every field, we have to validate the database, this process remove the error. if we failed to remove the error, second process is -copy the data to other destination and revise the above the process and work comfortably... good luck

Comment: In this case, it shows "Error Occurred in Selection." not "Error Occurred in Processing."